# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'multivariate_normal_frozen' and 'multivariate_normal_frozen'

Tags: python, scipy

What is the correct way to get the summation of two multivariate normal distributions?

Simple addition

```
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal

Z0 = multivariate_normal([1,2], [[2,0],[0,2]])
Z1 = multivariate_normal([1.1,2.2], [[2.1,0],[0,4.1]])

Z = Z0 + Z1

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'multivariate_normal_frozen' and 'multivariate_normal_frozen'
```

`sum(Z0, Z1)` also gives rise to

```
TypeError: 'multivariate_normal_frozen' object is not iterable
```

Comment: What does the docs say?

Comment: @hpaulj: Do you mean here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html ? I didn't see anything related to this case. Did I miss something?

Comment: Looks like you call a method like `pdf` to get a numpy array.  Those can be added.

Comment: If it's not documented it can't be done.  What's so puzzling about that?

Comment: @hpaulj: The first snippet example uses `pdf` for feeding only one mean and one covariance. I am trying to add two instances like the second snippet in which `pdf` is not required when one takes arrays into account for both means and covariances.

Comment: @hpaulj: If you and I don't know any hack for this, it doesn't mean it is impossible, as it is reasonable that one wants to add up two multivariate normal distributions. Anyhow, you don't have to spam in comments if you don't have anything constructive to add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that one needs to call `pdf()` for each instance before the summation:

```
Z = Z0.pdf() + Z1.pdf()
```

Comment: Do you mean `Z0.pdf(pos) + Z1.pdf(pos)`?  That makes arrays which can be added.